# How to restrict icons/readme.md from other users in apache?

Tags: apache

I want to restrict all directories and files to the end users, but the application should be accessible. I have restricted all directories except readme.md. I cannot even locate the file inside www folder. But the file is viewed when it is ran in the browser as follows.[image]

Following are the changes I have done in httpd.config file

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>

<Files "c:/wamp64/icons/readme.md">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all

</Files>

<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/*">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Apache 2.4 is my version

Comment: Apache has these default icons that are using when performing directory indexing. This is to make the user experience better in quickly identifying  the types of the files in the directory. Currently I am also fighting this issue and all I have found so far is that there are 2 places where the files could be located (`/usr/share/apache2/icons` or `/etc/httpd/icons`) On Debian I found them in the first path! Still trying to figure out ho to block the access to the readme.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that worked here: https://www.vntweb.co.uk/apache-restricting-access-to-iconsreadme/ I applied it to my server and then gave it a restart as reload did not take action for some reason. Afterwards, virtual hosts seem to be working fine. What i did is modified this file: `/etc/apache2/modes-available/alias.conf` to

```
<Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

and it did the trick